# Zip file is downloaded, but is malformed

Tags: node.js, typescript, zip

I have never used TypeScript before and I'm trying to write a simple function that downloads a zip file. So far, I have patched together this code:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import https from 'https';

export function handler(): void {
  https.get('https://data.humdata.org/dataset/3f976f27-2566-4ea7-b29e-7fc6ebc90aab/resource/060abaf3-8c9f-4df4-b7e3-5335a15c6247/download/world_port_index.zip', (res) => {
      // Pipe into local file                                                                                                                                                     
      res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./wpi.zip"));
  });
}
```

This gets the data and pipes it into a local file (`wpi.zip`). When I run this there is no error and the file is indeed created. Nevertheless, when trying to open the file I get the error that the file is an unsupported format. Presumably, there was an issue when writing to disk. When I download the file via a browser, the zip file isn't malformed, though, so I can rule out a sketchy source file.

Clearly, I've made a newbie mistake, but I'm unclear even where to begin with this. Is the function finishing before the full file has downloaded? (It looks about the right size, though.) Is there an encoding issue that I need to account for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This url `https://data.humdata.org/dataset/3f976f27-2566-4ea7-b29e-7fc6ebc90aab/resource/060abaf3-8c9f-4df4-b7e3-5335a15c6247/download/world_port_index.zip` redirects with status code `302`

You have to follow the redirect:

```
export function handler() {
  https.get('https://data.humdata.org/dataset/3f976f27-2566-4ea7-b29e-7fc6ebc90aab/resource/060abaf3-8c9f-4df4-b7e3-5335a15c6247/download/world_port_index.zip', (res) => {
    https.get(res.headers.location, res => {
      // Pipe into local file                                                                                                                                                     
      res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./wpi.zip"));
    })
  });
}
```

There are libraries that will do it automatically for you like `axios` or `fetch`